# excel macro to copy and paste + delete all contents

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a macro to open a workbook and copy the contents from the first workbook in cells H52:CO402 over to the workbook opened to cells B1 and on. Also if anyone could show me the code to completely clear the 2nd book that was opened before it pastes the information copied. The code I have so far is...

```
Sub copyandpaste()
'Inputs todays date
Range("ba58").Value = Date
ActiveSheet.Range("H52:CO402").Select
Selection.Copy
ChDir "R:\02. Common\0.6 Recall Rosters\Recall Roster"
Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
"R:\02. Common\0.6 Recall Rosters\Recall Roster\BETA-RecallRoster.xlsm"
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-135
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Protection"
Windows("BETA-RecallRoster.xlsm").Activate
Range("B1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste


ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Protection"
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: The second question is a great candidate for macro recording.  Developer --> Record Macro. Open the new sheet, select all and delete.  Developer --> Stop Recording.  Look at the code that was created.  May not be perfect, but it should get you pretty close.

Comment: yeah that's pretty much what this code here is. But it constantly gives me an error if the 2nd file has been saved since the last update.

Answer (score 0):

`Cells.Delete` will clear the contents of the current selected worksheet.